# custom base path play framework

Tags: java, playframework, configuration, playframework-2.0

Is there a way to configure a custom root base path for all the routes?

for example:

```
/login
/user
/group
```

but I want to prepend everything with:

```
/v1/login
/v1/user
/v1/group
```

anyway to do it via a application.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Suppose your `routes` file has the following routes

```
GET /login  controllers.login()
GET /user   controllers.user()
GET /group  controllers.group()
```

To achieve what you want, you just have to rename or move that rules to a new file (for example `v1.routes`) and then in the main `routes` file, use

```
->      /v1     v1.Routes
```

All the routes present in v1 file are now prepended with `v1`

Answer (score 3):

In current version (2.5) of play, the appropriate way is to add the desired base path to the ***play.http.context*** in the ***application.conf***

```
play.http.context="/v1"
```

Answer (score 1):

we can add the below in the application.conf

```
application.context="/v1"
```

Answer (score 0):

In play 2.8 you can specify a path prefix to your Router. With compiletime DI and macwire this looks like this:

```
  lazy val router: Router = {
    val prefix = "/v1"
    wire[Routes]
  }
```